# Scapy sniff not working

Tags: ip, scapy, packet

I am sending out packets on an interface ('enp0s9') and can verify that indeed packets are being sent on that interface with tcpdump.

I am trying to sniff those packets with scapy by doing the following:

```
packets = sniff(iface='enp0s9', store=0)
print str(packets)
```

yet nothing seems to happen. I am following the scapy cheat sheet but i don't know if i have wrong syntax. any help?

cheat sheet: https://blogs.sans.org/pen-testing/files/2016/04/ScapyCheatSheet_v0.2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
packets = sniff(iface='enp0s9', timeout=5)
print str(packets)
```

or just

```
sniff(iface='enp0s9', prn=lambda p: p.summary(), store=0)
```

---

#### Explanation

Sniff functions has a couple of arguments. You can check their meaning in scapy sources. Argument "store=0" means that packets storing will be disabled, so there will be no result.

You also need to stop sniffing after some time. You can use one of the following options:

- stop_filter: Python function applied to each packet to determine if we have to stop the capture after this packet.
- count: number of packets to capture. 0 means infinity.
- timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None).

As an alternative to such solution you can just use:

- prn: function to apply to each packet.